# How to mount host prefix in a url in Node.js or Swift?

Tags: node.js, swift, web-services, url, routes

I want to build api route for my web app. I want to achieve something like this - `http://api.localhost:80/home            //I want this`

Though I all found is to mount base uri as -

`http://localhost:80/api/index       //I don't want this`

Anybody know how to mount base api route prefix before host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is something called **subdomains** and it is a very useful thing that google implemented on its servers.

You can implement it in node.js (with express) by using a package called "express-subdomain".

Here is the npm page for it:
[express-subdomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain)

Comment: I hope there'd be an alternative for swift also. Like any server-side swift framework as in Perfect, Vapor, Kitura, etc. Anyway Thanks.

Comment: so sorry, but I have no experience in swift or mobile apps development